# Another slider to replace the Conveyor belt slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that the Conveyor belt slideshow script (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/leftrightslide.htm) runs perfectly. 
What I want just find another script works like that.

Can everyone suggest me another tool to run images from right to left in smoothly (not using Marquee - because at the first time, images do not show up, the box is empty - look not good)

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html

I think it will solve your problem

Comment: thanks, but that is not what I want, I just want a script supports image run from right to left smoothly

Comment: i am sorry but I didnt get your question can you explain what you want......May be i miss understood you.....

Comment: I am amazed that there are litteraly hundreds of carousels  all doing the same thing and only this script to do a slider!